# ListView can't set selected background color

Tags: java, android, listview, android-5.0-lollipop

I am attempting to change the list view item's background color upon selection.

In MainActivity:

```
leftDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
    navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<NavDrawerItem>();
    // adding nav drawer items to array
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[0], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(0, -1)));
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[1], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(1, -1)));
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[2], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(2, -1)));
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[3], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(3, -1), true, "22"));
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[4], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(4, -1)));
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[5], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(5, -1), true, "50+"));
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[6], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(6, -1), true, "99+"));
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[7], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(7, -1)));

    // Recycle the typed array
    navMenuIcons.recycle();

    // setting the nav drawer list adapter
    adapter = new NavDrawerListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),navDrawerItems);
    leftDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

    leftDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new SlideMenuClickListener());

    leftDrawerList.setItemChecked(0, true);

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);
```

My selector xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

  <item android:drawable="@drawable/list_item_bg_normal" android:state_activated="false"/>
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/list_item_bg_pressed" android:state_pressed="true"/>
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/list_item_bg_pressed" android:state_activated="true"/>

</selector>
```

My MainActivity layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<include layout="@layout/toolbar" />


<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- activity view -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:text="Activity Content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <!-- navigation drawer -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_gravity="left|start"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:divider="#FFFFFFFF"
            android:background="#FFFFFFFF"
            android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
            android:dividerHeight="0dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

My list item xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="48dp">
```

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
    android:textColor="@color/list_item_title"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingRight="40dp"/>

<TextView android:id="@+id/counter"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/counter_bg"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:textColor="@color/counter_text_color"/>
```

Yet, somehow, the color does not change upon selecting the item!

I have made sure that my colors are defined correctly.

Comment: You never set the color in your click listener.

Comment: Your selector XML is incomplete, and since that is where your problem would appear to lie, you might want to edit your question and provide the complete selector. Also, why are you using this both for the `listSelector` and for the `RelativeLayout` background?

Comment: I updated the code. Is it redundant to do both the listselector and the relative layout background of the list item?

Comment: check your order of your item in selector. android:state_activated should below android:state_pressed

Comment: "I updated the code" -- I fixed the formatting problem that was leaving out part of your XML. "Is it redundant to do both the listselector and the relative layout background of the list item?" -- if you are trying to use the activated state, that would be on the row background. The list selector is used for selection events (up/down presses on a D-pad, trackball, arrow keys. etc.). Beyond that, I agree with zzy, that your activated=true needs to appear before your default (your current first entry).

Comment: Thank you ! I reordered them as you two have suggested and it did work. However, I don't really know why it has to be that way, logically. If it's just a state that has been set for the item row, why should order matter...

Comment: @WayWay Android applies the first item in the state list that matches the current state of the object

Answer (score 0):

try setting `android:drawSelectorOnTop=true` for your `ListView`. like this:

```
<ListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:divider="#FFFFFFFF"
        android:background="#FFFFFFFF"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp" />
```